# Auto Indent in Emacs, Atom, and Sublime

Tags: emacs, sublimetext3, indentation, atom-editor, auto-indent

Given some programming language, editing a file for that language in Emacs generally leads to some nicer behavior with regards to indenting.  Emacs will automatically indent to the correct level when you hit RET.  That's a fairly common feature.  In addition, when you hit TAB on a line in Emacs, it will automatically indent to the correct level, and if the line is already indented correctly, *do nothing*.

Is it possible to get the second behavior in either Atom or Sublime?  Responses for other editors, welcome, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an *emacs-mode* in every 'important' text-editor. Take it, customize it and you'll have the emacs-features you want.

For example, in atom you can take the [emacs-mode](https://atom.io/packages/emacs-mode). In SublimeText : [sublemacspro](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro).

Even in brackets : [brackets-emacs](https://github.com/ahmadnazir/brackets-emacs) !